# Ionic platform (ionic.io) social providers for authentication

Tags: ionic-framework

I was trying to authenticate with google using ionic platform social providers. In documentation they just have a line of code

```
Ionic.Auth.login('google', {'remember': true}).then(authSuccess, authFailure);
```

Calling this just shows a blank page, should this not open an inappbrowser window with google signing page ? Can someone help please..

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through the same issues.

Make sure you have all the bits (ionic, cordova and platforms) up-to-date and the inAppBrowser (latest version) installed.

Confirm settings at providers.

Confirm your networking is working? You should get a timeout if it fails here.